# add events to CalendarBundle in symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, calendar

I installed CalendarBundle - jQuery fullcalendar by following the tutorial on this link: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle and I succeeded to display the calendar. But the problem is that I can't add events by clicking on the calendar despite I added an Event Listener class by following this part of the tutorial: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle#adding-events. In addition I don't know how to deal with database using the bundle I installed.

So, what shall I do exactly??

I have rendered calender from new bundle named as AppBundle and as instructed added CalendarEventListener.php class in folder EventListener. Below is the code for CalendarEventListener.php

```
<?php


   namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

   use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
   use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

   class CalendarEventListener
 {

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
{
    $startDate = $calendarEvent->getStartDatetime();
    $endDate = $calendarEvent->getEndDatetime();

    // The original request so you can get filters from the calendar
    // Use the filter in your query for example

    $request = $calendarEvent->getRequest();
    $filter = $request->get('filter');


    // load events using your custom logic here,
    // for instance, retrieving events from a repository

    $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:MyCompanyEvents')
                      ->createQueryBuilder('company_events')
                      ->where('company_events.event_datetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
                      ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                      ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                      ->getQuery()->getResult();

    // $companyEvents and $companyEvent in this example
    // represent entities from your database, NOT instances of EventEntity
    // within this bundle.
    //
    // Create EventEntity instances and populate it's properties with data
    // from your own entities/database values.

    //echo sizeof($companyEvents);
    foreach($companyEvents as $companyEvent) {

        // create an event with a start/end time, or an all day event
        if ($companyEvent->getAllDayEvent() === false) {
            $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), $companyEvent->getEndDatetime());
        } else {
            $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), null, true);
        }


        //optional calendar event settings
        $eventEntity->setAllDay(true); // default is false, set to true if this is an all day event
        $eventEntity->setBgColor('#FF0000'); //set the background color of the event's label
        $eventEntity->setFgColor('#FFFFFF'); //set the foreground color of the event's label
        $eventEntity->setUrl('http://www.google.com'); // url to send user to when event label is clicked
        $eventEntity->setCssClass('my-custom-class'); // a custom class you may want to apply to event labels

        //finally, add the event to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
        $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
    }
}
```

}

And lastly i have also added service.xml in AppBundle/Resource/Config/service.xml
Below is the code for service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services">

   <services>
    <service id="appbundle.calendar_listener" class="AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="calendar.load_events" method="loadEvents" />
    </service>

</services>
```

It is not showing error but at the same time events are not added too.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you register your event loading service in the same bundle as your ADesigns. Another thing is check in your network tab if request is sent to the Calendar controller and what response you are getting. If not update your routing file accordingly.

Comment: So you are correct there was problem in routing file and service.xml path!